# Why doesn't `eval` work in this code?

Tags: variable, ffmpeg, eval

I wrote the following code which is meant to create a file with a list of low-resolution media files:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

find "$PWD" -type f -iname "*.avi" -execdir ~/CS/SoftwareDevelopment/MySoftware/Bash/lowresolution_finder/printer.sh {} + >~/pCloudDrive/VisualArts/lowres.films
find "$PWD" -type f -iname "*.mkv" -execdir ~/CS/SoftwareDevelopment/MySoftware/Bash/lowresolution_finder/printer.sh {} + >>~/pCloudDrive/VisualArts/lowres.films
find "$PWD" -type f -iname "*.mp4" -execdir ~/CS/SoftwareDevelopment/MySoftware/Bash/lowresolution_finder/printer.sh {} + >>~/pCloudDrive/VisualArts/lowres.films
```

As you can see the above code calls `printer.sh` which in turn executes the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

#The script is meant to print only the results of low resolution, that is starting with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

if [[ $(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height -of csv=s=x:p=0 $1) == 2* ]]; then
  echo "$(realpath $1)" && ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height -of csv=s=x:p=0 $1 
elif [[ $(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height -of csv=s=x:p=0 $1) == 3* ]]; then
  echo "$(realpath $1)" && ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height -of csv=s=x:p=0 $1 
elif [[ $(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height -of csv=s=x:p=0 $1) == 4* ]]; then
  echo "$(realpath $1)" && ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height -of csv=s=x:p=0 $1 
elif [[ $(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height -of csv=s=x:p=0 $1) == 5* ]]; then
  echo "$(realpath $1)" && ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height -of csv=s=x:p=0 $1 

fi
```

Wanting to substitute repetitions in my code with variables I modified `printer.sh` :

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

output=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height -of csv=s=x:p=0 $1)
if [[ $($output) == 2* ]]; then
  echo "$(realpath $1)" && eval "$output"
elif [[ $($output) == 3* ]]; then
  echo "$(realpath $1)" && eval "$output"
elif [[ $($output) == 4* ]]; then
  echo "$(realpath $1)" && eval "$output"
elif [[ $($output) == 5* ]]; then
  echo "$(realpath $1)" && eval "$output" 
fi
```

Now it does not work and I get the output that looks like this:

```
/home/jerzy/CS/SoftwareDevelopment/MySoftware/Bash/lowresolution_finder/printer.sh: line 6: 1920x1024: command not found
/home/jerzy/CS/SoftwareDevelopment/MySoftware/Bash/lowresolution_finder/printer.sh: line 8: 1920x1024: command not found
/home/jerzy/CS/SoftwareDevelopment/MySoftware/Bash/lowresolution_finder/printer.sh: line 10: 1920x1024: command not found
/home/jerzy/CS/SoftwareDevelopment/MySoftware/Bash/lowresolution_finder/printer.sh: line 12: 1920x1024: command not found
/home/jerzy/CS/SoftwareDevelopment/MySoftware/Bash/lowresolution_finder/printer.sh: line 6: 1920x800: command not found
/home/jerzy/CS/SoftwareDevelopment/MySoftware/Bash/lowresolution_finder/printer.sh: line 8: 1920x800: command not found
/home/jerzy/CS/SoftwareDevelopment/MySoftware/Bash/lowresolution_finder/printer.sh: line 10: 1920x800: command not found
/home/jerzy/CS/SoftwareDevelopment/MySoftware/Bash/lowresolution_finder/printer.sh: line 12: 1920x800: command not found
```

What have I done wrong? How should I rewrite it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you want is something like:

```bsh
output=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height -of csv=s=x:p=0 "$1")
if [[ $output == [2345]* ]]
then 
  echo "$(realpath "$1")" "$output"
fi
```

I'm not sure why you used `eval` here at all. `eval` is used to execute strings that contain shell code. The output of `ffprobe` isn't code.

Comment: Your code works fine, thanks. Your point about `eval` is right, when I substituted the lines containing it with something like `echo "$(realpath $1) $output"` it all started to work very well. `[2345]` looks like regex, is it?Why not using `[2-5]` instead?Any difference between the two?

Comment: @JerzyBrzóska `[2345]` in this case is still a shell glob/wildcard pattern, and you can use `[2-5]` too.

Comment: Though it's likely not to be a problem here, `[2-5]` would match a lot more characters than `[2345]` would. Here with bash 5.1.8 on a GNU system and a British locale, I find it matches on `2345٢٣٤۲۳۴߂߃߄२३४২৩৪੨੩੪૨૩૪୨୩୪௨௩௪౨౩౪౺౻౽౾೨೩೪൨൩൪෨෩෪๒๓๔໒໓໔༢༣༤༫༬༭၂၃၄႒႓႔፪፫፬២៣៤៲៳៴᠒᠓᠔᥈᥉᥊᧒᧓᧔᪂᪃᪄᪒᪓᪔᭒᭓᭔᮲᮳᮴᱂᱃᱄᱒᱓᱔⁴₂₃₄⅔⅖⅗⅘⅜②③④⑳⑵⑶⑷⒇⒉⒊⒋⒛⓴⓶⓷⓸❷❸❹➁➂➃➋➌➍〢〣〤㉉㉊㉋㉑㉒㉓㉔㉕㉖㉗㉘㉙㉚㉛㉜㉝㉞㉟㊱㊲㊳㊴㊵㊶㊷㊸㊹㊺㊻㊼㊽㊾㋁㋂㋃㍚㍛㍜㍬㍭㍮㍯㍰㏡㏢㏣㏳㏴㏵㏶㏷㏸㏹㏺㏻㏼㏽㏾꘢꘣꘤꣒꣓꣔꤂꤃꤄꧒꧓꧔꧲꧳꧴꩒꩓꩔꯲꯳꯴２３４` and many more which won't fit in a comment.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I recognize some Asian digits there (Japanese, Malayalam, Hindi), and it's surprising to me that most of those seem to have only the digits for 2, 3 and 4 in them, but not 5. Intriguing. Similarly with the special numbers too (e.g., `➋➌➍`).

Comment: `[2-5]` will include the ones that sort between `2` and `5`. ASCII `5` is likely the one that comes first among all 5-like characters.

Comment: You may have noticed ² is missing which would be linked to the [quite buggy way bash handles ranges](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2021-02/msg00054.html).